# PHP and shared_memory: how to detect 'free space' in the shared memory segment?

Tags: php, shared-memory

I create a 1MB space of shread memory for my app.

Every user as ONE and only ONE array with some info, accesible from about 10 concurrent processes, and on its monitor, user can see the progress of every process.

Evey process clean it's owned values from client's array.

But .. in a growing situation ... 1 milion user with each one 1 empty array 'at every single moment in time' will give me this

> shm_put_var(): not enough shared memory left

... How can i detect when size of shared area is 'low' ? So I can grow it

EDIT: i'm usuing shm_ functionts (for example [shm_get_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-get-var.php))

In this set of function, nothing tell me that space is low before data in memory was corrupted ...

Comment: That isn't telling you the area is low, its telling you its corrupted...its different from lacking space.

Comment: yes, I edited the question... I copy/pasted the wrong row from log

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that when composing a question you have a toolbar with several buttons to enter source code, add cites and create links. Make sure you use them from now own ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shell command, but this is dependent on what your hosting-service allows, if you so use that.

With shell_exec() you can call the a system function to read the task manager of your operating system.

For OSX for example you can use the "top" command line function to retrieve the free memory live. Easiest might be to just dump the whole activity-table and use regex to fetch the PHP process(es).

Comment: Uhm... I need to know the free space left in the shared memory segment I'm using...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear; You can read memory_get_usage() and also fetch the live free memory through using SHELL commands. This way you can compare the usages to suit your needs. On OSX you can fetch the Activity Monitor table in Terminal (thus; bash/shell) and fetch the live memory usage. The command is "top"

Comment: No I'm not clear, not you.
I mean: I need to know the free space left on a specific segment of shared memory

Comment: In the "top" command in OSX "RSHRD" shows the Physical Shared Memory of a process. Can you specify your OS? I can maybe answer your question better to your needs :)

Comment: actually my server is running on a Debian. I'll repeat: i'm not asking how to detect free memory in the system. From PHP i 'take' a shared memory segment of 1024 byte, for example. I put some vars into it, and I want to detect how much space of  my specific 1024 byte segment is actually free. This is because i'm not able to predict the exact amount and type of vars setted into  it. And when segment is full, my script will crash

Comment: Alright, then your answers are here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php When you assign a piece of shared memory ( shmop_open() ) you can get the data size ( shmop_size ) of a segment dynamically. I hope this helps. Might I also ask why specifically want to control memory with such old methods? :)

Comment: I'm not using shmop extension, i'm using the one with shm_get_var [semaphore function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php]

Comment: Sadly it seems you can only limit the memory usage and not read it live. In your case I would still recommend to live-evaluate the shared memory. Each PHP instance should be a different process on Debian so you probably can check the shared memories individually. The problem would be you can't then identify them right. The last option would be to still fall back to another lib (like shmop) that 'can' provide the size of shared memory per segment, but that would really depend on the amount of code you already written :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could estimate the size of the objects you cache and keep track of the remaining space yourself, by using utility functions like those:

```
public static function getSize($object){
    return self::formatBytes(strlen(serialize($object)));
}

public static function formatBytes($bytes, $precision=2){
    $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');
    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
    $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024));
    $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1);    
    $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);
    return round($bytes, $precision).' '.$units[$pow];
}
```

This might not be always 100% accurate, but should come close to the real object size.